# doghnut chart control in asp.net with label

Tags: asp.net, charts

i am using doghnut chart for creation of chart
what i want is the sum of all number should appear inside the doghnuts like '115 Ticket'
between the circle like lable.
how can i able to get this?

can you please reply ASAP
Thanks in advance